# Simultaneous Linear Equations for single variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

If $x^3=a+1$ and $x+(b/x)=a$ Then $x$ equals??
Please help in solving these equations. I can't get it how to solve $1$ variable by two equations

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ supposed to be unknowns or parameters? Are they (and $x$) real, integer, natural numbers?

Comment: Sorryt I forgot to tell.x is the variable.a and b are constant natural numbers please keep the answer in terms of a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $x+\dfrac{b}{x}=a$ is equivalent to $x^2=ax-b$. Now multiplying this by $x$ yields
$$a+1=x^3=ax^2-bx=a(ax-b)-bx=(a^2-b)x-ab,$$
and thus $x=\dfrac{1+a+ab}{a^2-b}$. Note that there must be some conditions on $a$ and $b$ for this to hold!

Answer (score 0):

You have actually three unknowns and only two equation so the value of $x$ is not unique. One has for example, the integer solutions (*which is not necessary*)
$$(x,a,b)=(2,7,35),(1,0,-1),(3,26,69)$$ and infinitely many more (*take a value of $a$ such that $a+1$ be a cube so you have a value for $x$ and a value for $b$*).

Comment: You are welcome.